# Looking to access map object from other function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have initialized a map with infoboxes, now when I try to access the map variable from the other function (the one capture my location on click of link Get Location) I get map is not defined I understand that it gets executed before the variable is available but I havent been able to find a way out for this.
Any pointer / help in this will be appreciated , Thank you in advance

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false";
    // document.body.appendChild(script);
 var map;
 initialize();

    });   
   function showPosition(){
    // Try HTML5 geolocation
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
   var map;
   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
   
   var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
   //jQuery('#findMe').data('pos',pos);
    
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({   
     map: map,
     position: pos,
     zoom:7

    });
    // infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     // map: map,
     // position: pos,
     // content: 'You Are Here'
     // });
     map.setCenter(pos);
     
   }, function() {
     handleNoGeolocation(true);
   });
    } else {
   // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
   handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }
    return false;
    }
   function initialize() {
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
  zoom: 8
    };
 
 
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);
      
    var markers = [['',35.2152241,-80.84801900000002,''],
['',35.1995636,-80.82525329999999,''],
['',35.1585635,-80.79616499999997,''],
['',35.201245,-80.86516999999998,''],
['',35.19604558956503,-80.84856033325195,''],
['',35.197692,-80.82809299999997,''],
['',35.0658382,-80.76834389999999,''],
['',35.1786109,-80.851946,' '],
['',35.1304041,-80.8324773,''],
['',35.201245,-80.86516999999998,'  '],
['',35.2136068,-80.79125290000002,' '],
];
 
var infoWindowContent = [['<div class="info_content">test content<\/div>'],
['<div class="info_content">test content<\/div>'],
['<div class="info_content">test content<\/div>'],
['<div class="info_content">test content<\/div>'],
['<div class="info_content">test content<\/div>'],
['<div class="info_content">test content<\/div>'],
['<div class="info_content">test content<\/div>'],
['<div class="info_content">test content<\/div>'],
['<div class="info_content">test content<\/div>'],
['<div class="info_content">test content<\/div>'],
];
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        var itype = markers[i][3];
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0]
        });
          
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
    }
```

```css
#map_canvas{
width:100%;height:400px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.0&sensor=false"></script>

<a href='#' class='detectLoc' onclick="return showPosition()">Get My lcoation</a>
    <div id="map_canvas" class="mapping"></div>
```

Comment: remove the `var map` inside your `initialize()`, the problem is that you are declaring it twice: globally and within the scope of the initialize function. If you want to have access to it throughout the global scope, do not declare it again. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a global variable to store the 'map'. Also here you have declared variable map in each and every function. This will shadow the global variable and local one will be used always resulting in undefined. In the code below I added a global map variable and commented re-declarations for map variable in functions *showPosition()* and *initialize()*

```
var map;    // global map variable

jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false";
        // document.body.appendChild(script);
        var map;
        initialize();

        });   
          function showPosition(){
              // Try HTML5 geolocation
              if(navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                //var map;
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
                //jQuery('#findMe').data('pos',pos);

                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({   
                        map: map,
                        position: pos,
                        zoom:7

                    });
                    // infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        // map: map,
                        // position: pos,
                        // content: 'You Are Here'
                     // });
                     map.setCenter(pos);

                }, function() {
                  handleNoGeolocation(true);
                });
              } else {
                // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
                handleNoGeolocation(false);
              }
              return false;
        }
       function initialize() {
        //var map;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var mapOptions = {
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
            zoom: 8
        };


        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        map.setTilt(45);

        var markers = [['',35.2152241,-80.84801900000002,''],
    ['',35.1995636,-80.82525329999999,''],
    ['',35.1585635,-80.79616499999997,''],
    ['',35.201245,-80.86516999999998,''],
    ['',35.19604558956503,-80.84856033325195,''],
    ['',35.197692,-80.82809299999997,''],
    ['',35.0658382,-80.76834389999999,''],
    ['',35.1786109,-80.851946,' '],
    ['',35.1304041,-80.8324773,''],
    ['',35.201245,-80.86516999999998,'  '],
    ['',35.2136068,-80.79125290000002,' '],
    ];

    var infoWindowContent = [['<div class="info_content">test content<\/div>'],
    ['<div class="info_content">test content<\/div>'],
    ['<div class="info_content">test content<\/div>'],
    ['<div class="info_content">test content<\/div>'],
    ['<div class="info_content">test content<\/div>'],
    ['<div class="info_content">test content<\/div>'],
    ['<div class="info_content">test content<\/div>'],
    ['<div class="info_content">test content<\/div>'],
    ['<div class="info_content">test content<\/div>'],
    ['<div class="info_content">test content<\/div>'],
    ];
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

        for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
            var itype = markers[i][3];
            bounds.extend(position);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                title: markers[i][0]
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));

            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
        }
```